# Simple question on the linearity of a dynamical system

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, functions, dynamical-systems

Take a continuous-time dynamical system $\Sigma=(\mathbb{T},\mathbb{W},\mathfrak{B})$ with $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{W}=\mathbb{R}$ and all sinusoidal signals with period $2\pi$.

i.e. $w:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\in\mathfrak{B}\iff\exists A\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $\varphi\in[0,2\pi)$ such that $w(t)=A\sin{(t+\varphi)}$.

I want to work out whether this dynamical system is linear or not. We know that $\Sigma$ is linear if $\mathbb{W}$ is a vector space and $\mathfrak{B}$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{W}^{\mathbb{T}}$.

$\mathbb{W}=\mathbb{R}$, which is a vector space.

$\mathbb{W}^{\mathbb{T}}=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}=\{\text{all maps } \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\}$

$\mathfrak{B}=\{w:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}|\exists A\in\mathbb{R}_{+}\text{ and }\varphi\in[0,2\pi)\text{ such that }w(t)=A\sin{(t+\varphi)}\}$

$w$  maps $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, which should imply that $\mathfrak{B}\subset\mathbb{W}^{\mathbb{T}}$, but since $\sin{(t+\varphi)}\ne\sin{(t)}+\sin{(\varphi)}$ and thus is not linear, does that imply that the dynamical system is not linear?

Comment: You slightly misinterpreting linearity in this case. It should be understood as "the sum of two elements of $\mathfrak{B}$ is again an element of $\mathfrak{B}$". I mean, given two elements $A_1 \sin (t + \phi_1)$ and $A_2 \sin (t + \phi_2)$ their sum is again an element of form $A^\ast \sin (t + \phi^\ast)$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: @Evgeny $$\begin{aligned}w_{1}(t)+w_{2}(t)&=A_{1}\sin{(t+\varphi_{1})}+A_{2}\sin{(t+ \varphi_{2})}\\&=\Re\{A_{1}e^{i\varphi_{1}}e^{it}\}+\Re\{A_{2}e^{i\varphi_{2}}e^{it}\}\\&=\Re\{A_{1}e^{i\varphi_{1}}e^{it}+A_{2}e^{i\varphi_{2}}e^{it}\}\\&=\Re\{(A_{1}e^{i\varphi_{1}}+A_{2}e^{i\varphi_{2}})e^{it}\}\\&=\Re\{(A_{3}e^{i\varphi_{3}})e^{it}\}\\&=A_{3}\sin{(t+\varphi_{3})}\end{aligned}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I've meant :)